# vim: Tagbar windows opened when typing <Enter> in normal mode

Tags: vim, tagbar

When typing <Enter> in normal mode in Vim with the Tagbar plugin installed, the Tagbar window is opened automatically. I want to disable this functionality. What must I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping for `<C-m>` is actually the cause of the Enter key opening Tagbar. If you remove that map from your vimrc, the enter key will no longer trigger `:TagbarToggle`.

[Mappings for `<C-m>` and `<CR>` (Enter) are synonymous in Vim:](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_2)#Key_notation)

> The following table shows the mapping between some of the keys on the keyboard and the equivalent Ctrl-key combination:
>
> Ctrl-I      Tab
> Ctrl-[      Esc
> Ctrl-M      Enter
> Ctrl-H      Backspace
>
> If you use one of the Ctrl-key combination in the above table in a map, the map also applies to the corresponding key. Both the keys produce the same key scan code. For example, if you create a map for CTRL-I, then you can invoke the map by pressing Ctrl-I or the Tab key.

This means when you set `nmap <C-m> :TagbarToggle<CR>`, it is the same as
also setting `nmap <CR> :TagbarToggle<CR>`.

You'll probably want to choose a new key instead of M. The alternative is to
change the key code sent by `<C-m>` at the operating system level with some
remapping program.

The terminal key bindings come from readline, the program that processes input text in
your terminal prompt. A full list of key bindings is in the [readline
manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readline).

You can find more info about Vim key codes by typing `:help keycodes` in Vim, or reading the help docs [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#keycodes).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. It works perfectly.

Comment: @LongMaX happy to help! Since this solved it, please mark it as the accepted answer to help others who might face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

put the flowing code in you .vimrc

```
unmap <cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :help tagbar to open the documentation. It sounds like you might have a mapping in your vimrc file that says something like

```
nnoremap <silent> <CR> :TagbarToggle<CR>
```

or

```
nnoremap <silent> <CR> :TagbarOpen<CR>
```

if you find and remove that mapping  will no longer open Tagbar

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I grepped for the keyboard remapping of TagbarToggle and TagbarOpen command in all my vim configuration files. I had remapped TagbarToggle only on <C-m>, not <slient> <CR>. I could not see any other remapping.